# MYSQL - get value from position of comma-separated-string

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I have a field in my table like this:

`fox,cat,bear,horse,dog`

With FIND_IN_SET I can find if the value is in that string and get back the position of it.
There is a way to get value of a determinate position?

for example:

```
position 3 = bear
position 2 = cat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use substring_index twice in this way (change 2 to whichever item you want to extract):

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, ',', 2), ',', - 1)
from t
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/ORKXSV19583)

Comment: Couldn't run the demo, it said "This language is for patrons only.". But you are my life saver. thx!